# Where to ask an identification question on a series

Tags: discussion, support

I have asked an identification question about an episode in the "Monk" series, but I was told this is off-topic on "Movies and TV". OK.

But it must be on-topic somewhere else, right?

For SF&F stories or movies, I know where to ask for story-identification and I did it often. But for a series which has nothing to do with SF&F where do I have to ask ?

Thank you for help.